# Name of a simple communication / coordination game

Tags: game-theory

Is there a name for the game with extensive form given in the image below? Are there any references that study it? I am not well versed in game theory so I would appreciate any pointers. I am sure it isn't new.

It seems like a simple example of a game where only one player has access to some information (here just a single bit) that the second player needs to make the right move. The two players must then coordinate so that the second player knows how to interpret the first player's move.

More specifically, if nature (here denoted $W$) plays $x$ then player two (denoted $A_2$) has to play $x$ as well for both players to get payoff $1$ else both players get payoff $0$. Only $A_1$ sees the move by nature and $A_2$ only sees the move by $A_1$. So the players must coordinate either so that when $A_1$ plays $x$ it means that $W$ played $x$ or when $A_1$ plays $x$ it means that $W$ played $(1-x) \mod 2$.

[image: extensive form representation of the game]

Comment: Looks like an extensive form game with incomplete information. What is the type of questions you are trying to answer?

Comment: @YJT I am really just looking for references and/or an established name for this game. It could be that it isn't special enough to have its own name (like prisoner's dilemma or stag hunt or so) maybe it's not even discussed anywhere as an example? I don't have any particular question about this game beyond that. I want to discuss it in a paper and if possible give existing references / background to it.

Comment: Basically, when studying extensive form games, after finishing the first examples of games with complete information (chess-like), the next step is games with incomplete information. Any textbook on should have it, for example, my favorite, Zamir, Maschler & Solan (chapter 3).